# Magento admin panel not loading(404 error) after Changing Allow Magneto backend to run on frame

Tags: magento

[image]I have changed System > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > Security > Allow Magento Backend to run in frame from it's default "Only from same domain" to "Enabled" and  I am not able to login to my admin panel. it says 404 not found.
I want to reset back to "only from same domain" from the (script/.htaccess) backend.

Is it possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should not be a problem - you could try to clear your cache folders with `rm -rf <YOUR MAGENTO ROOT>/var/*`.

If that does not help you can set this setting back to "Only from same origin" via database query.

For that please run the following command on your Magento database:

```sql
UPDATE core_config_data SET value=2 WHERE `path`='admin/security/domain_policy_backend';
```

Comment: I tried what you said but cannot clear cache there are folders still remain mage- -9,mage --8, mage --0, mage --a..still cant access my admin panel page..

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Did you run the mysql query? If the clearing of the cache does not help, set the setting back with the mysql query I mentioned.

Comment: I tried your query and I get 404 not found error on my admin panel

Comment: Did you change anything else? Is your shop online so I could check? Furthermore... in your screenshot you set "Allow Magento FRONTEND.." but we are talking about the backend/admin , right?

Comment: No I have not changed anything mostly except front end frame and backend frame security options .. its not online.

Comment: _I tried what you said but cannot clear cache there are folders still remain mage- -9,mage --8, mage --0, mage --a..still cant access my admin panel page.._ Typical permissions/ownership problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the following steps to resolve this 404 error. Hope might help someone.This error  has been resolved by programming.

```
Go to your cpanel and launch phpMyAdmin.
    Locate your Magento Database and select the core_config_data table.
    Locate and edit the following rows:
        Scope:"Default" and Path:"admin/url/custom"
            Select the NULL checkbox and save.
    Scope:"Default" and Path:"admin/url/use_custom"
            Change value from 1 to 0 and save.
        Scope:"Default" and Path:"admin/url/use_custom_path"
            Change value from 1 to 0 if it isn't already and save.
    Locate and delete the following rows:
        Scope:"Stores" and Path:"web/secure/base_url"
        Scope:"Stores" and Path:"web/unsecure/base_url" (should be located on the last page)
    Delete /var/cache folder
```